# Sort data from text file in a HTML table

Tags: php, html, sorting, html-table, text-files

I have a script that collects data from a text file and displays it in a HTML table. It is pretty simple coded. But what I want to do is have the table display the results sorted by the `.$parts[1].` column. As the script is now, it displays the result sorted by the `.$parts[0].` column.

I have tried to get it to work with `usort`, but I have given up.

This is my code:

```
<table class="heavyTable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Length</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <?php
       $file_handle = fopen("bardate_domains.txt", "rb");

       while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
         $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
         $parts = explode(' ', $line_of_text);  
         $tmp = explode('.', $parts[0]);
         echo "<tr><td>".$parts[0]."</td><td>".$parts[1]."</td><td>".strlen($tmp[0])."</td></tr>";
       }
       fclose($file_handle);
     ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I appreciate any help I can get :)

EDIT:
The text file looks like this:

```
0086.se 2017-04-02
0102design.se 2017-03-03
0141.se 2017-04-21
0158.se 2017-03-27
016fotboll.se 2017-03-31
020716.se 2017-04-12
021webb.se 2017-04-23
```

In total there is about 40.000 lines.

Comment: wath type of data is $data[0]?

Comment: I updated the original post with sample data from the text file.

Comment: then you must first explode, load into array sort it, and then do the echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $fileHandler = fopen("bardate_domains.txt", "rb");
    $data = [];

    while (!feof($fileHandler) ) {
        // read file row
        $row = fgets($fileHandler);

        $index = count($data);

        // explode array by space
        $data[$index] = explode(' ', $row);

        // explode data[$index][0] by '.', then insert into array in index 0 & 1
        array_splice($data[$index], 0, 1, explode('.', $data[$index][0]));
    }

    // sort array by array index 1
    usort($data, function ($prev, $next) {
        if ($prev[1] == $next[1]) {
            return 0;
        }

        return ($prev[1] < $next[1]) ? -1 : 1;
    });

    fclose($fileHandler);
?>

<table class="heavyTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Length</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($data as $item): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $item[0] . '.' . $item[1] ?></td>
                <td><?= $item[2] ?></td>
                <td><?= $item[1] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you but when I run this I get HTTP 500 error. I can not give you anymore information since I am not at home at the moment.

Comment: PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in your code on line 9
    index = count($data);

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `$` on line 9: `index = count($data);`, it ought to be `$index = count($data);`.

Comment: Thank you. I get no errors in the code now but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [usort](http://php.net/usort) function and provide your own sort function like this:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

But you must retrieve all array elements first and sort them after that you can print them out.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you are creating your table line by line, so the output will be a table sorted in the order of the lines of the text file, if and only if the text file is sorted by `.$parts[0]` that's how the table will be sorted.

I don't think there is any (simple) way to sort a html table once created, so you should probably sort the data before creating the table.